# Instance of C++ template class as a member of another template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

Let's say I have following templated C++ class

```
#include <cstdint>      

template <uint32_t NO_POINTS>
class A
{
public:
  struct Point
  {
    float x;
    float y;
  };

  A(const Point (&points)[NO_POINTS])
  {
      for (uint32_t point = 0; point < NO_POINTS; point++) {
          table[point] = points[point];
      }
  }
  
private:
  Point table[NO_POINTS];
};
```

and I would like to use an instance of this class as a private member of the following class:

```
#include "A.h"

template <uint32_t NO_LUT_POINTS>
class B
{

public:
  B(A<NO_LUT_POINTS>::Point (&table)[NO_LUT_POINTS]) : lut(table){}

private:
  A<NO_LUT_POINTS> lut;
};

#include "B.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     B<4> foo({{1326.0, 25.0},   {1601.0, 30.0},   {1922.0, 35.0},   {2293.0, 40.0}});
           
    return 0;
}
```

I have attempted to compile this code but the compiler reports following error
`A<NO_LUT_POINTS>::Point is not a type`. I don't understand what the reason for this error is. Can anybody explain to me why the compiler reports this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake with types nested in template classes. You need to add `typename` to tell the compiler that `Point` is a type.

```
...
public:
  B(typename A<NO_LUT_POINTS>::Point const (&table)[NO_LUT_POINTS]) : lut(table){}
...
```

Beyond solving your problem, however, please notice that `Point` doesn't depend on the template parameters of `A`, so you should not nest it in that class.   This would remove the necessity for adding `typename`.

Comment: ...and it has to be a constant referece if they want to pass a temporary

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Good point. I added a `const`.